# When dynamic variables are released from memory in C?

Tags: c, malloc

I would like to know, when is the pointer p released in the code? Is it considered as a local variable and released at the end of foo function?

Also, when is *p released? I'm assuming it's never released.

I know that free releases the memory allocated by malloc. But I'm having trouble understanding the difference between p and *p, which one is considered to be "the memory" which is released ?

```
int foo()
{
    int *p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    .
    . //free is not called
}
```

Comment: If `free` is not called then it is a memory leak  - it does not get freed when the function ends. `p` is the address of the memory. `*p` is the first content of the memory.

Comment: `p` is a local variable in the function foo.  When `foo` returns, its memory is released.  The memory location allocated by `malloc`  will not be freed until the program terminates.

Comment: Do you code some C software running on some operating system (which one? Try [Debian](https://debian.org/)....), or do you code a "bare metal" C software? Consider using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) as your compiler, using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and use also [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/)

Comment: @WilliamPursell So *p will not be released?

Comment: @Sam12 The value of `p` is the address that was returned by `malloc`.  That location is never freed.  `*p` is a value stored at the location that is never being freed.  It doesn't really make sense to talk about `*p` being freed; `*p` is an integer.  It is stored at  a memory location that is not freed.

Comment: Note that `int foo()` has been deprecated for many years.  Use `int foo(void)`

Comment: You need to differentiate between the heap storage managed with `malloc` and `free`, and the automatic variable storage for variables which is managed by the compiler. If you had, for example, and plain `int` variable like `int i;` then its life-time would be managed by the compiler, and any memory occupied by `i` would be released when the life-time of the variable ends (like the end of the function its defined in). The life-time of heap-allocated memory, as allocated by `malloc`, doesn't end at all, until you explicitly `free` it.

Answer (score 2):

Inside a function body, `int *p` tells the compiler (or C implementation) to allocate memory for `p`. This allocation is automatic, and the release of the memory used for `p` is automatic when execution of the block the declaration is in ends.

When `malloc(sizeof(int))` executes, it attempts to allocate enough memory for an `int`. This allocation is manual. The memory is released only when the program executes a call to `free` or some related routine that frees memory (such as `realloc` to allocate new memory and free the old memory).

The allocations of the memory for `p` and the memory that `p` points to are unrelated. There is no binding between `p` and `*p` other than the fact that the address of `*p` is is stored in `p`. You could do this:

```
{
    int *q;
    {
        int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
        // Now p points to allocated memory.
        *p = 3;
        q = p;
        // Now q points to the allocated memory.
    }
    // Now p no longer exists in the C model of computing.
    // The memory used for p has been released.
    // The memory allocated with malloc is still allocated.
    printf("%d\n", *q);  // Prints “3”.
    free(q);
    // Now the allocated memory has been released.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After the call to `malloc`, `p` will contain the address of the memory allocated by `malloc`.

So `p` is a (local) variable and `*p` is the allocated memory.

The allocated memory (`*p`) is released by a call to `free`, which never occurs in your code (this is called a "memory leak").

The local variable `p` is on the stack and is automatically released when the function returns (but `*p` is *not* automatically released!)

Comment: I think this is poorly worded.  `*p` is an integer.  The value of `p` is the address of memory that is never released.  `&p` is released when the function returns.    It would seem more accurate to say `&p` is released when the function returns, but `p` is not automatically released....but I think both phrasings can lead to confusion.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: `&p` is not released; **memory** is allocated or released, not addresses.

Comment: Why is &p released?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Why is p is not considered as an address in this case?

Comment: `&p` is the variable `p` on the stack. It is released when the function returns. It may be a bit overdone to call it `&p` which semantically is just the variable `p` (which has an address which is on the stack).

Comment: @WilliamPursell: The phrasing is okay. Re “`*p` is an integer”: `*p` is an lvalue. Per C 2018 6.3.2.1, “An *lvalue* is an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially designates an object…” Per 3.15 1, an object is “region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent value”. So `*p` is a region of data storage; it **is** the memory that was allocated.

Comment: `p` is a name that exists only at compile time.  When we talk about `p`, are we talking about the value at runtime, or the region of data storage that value occupies?   You (@EricPostpischil) seem to be using the latter, while I seem to be using the former.  You are probably being more precise.

Answer (score 0):

There are two pieces of memory involved - the variable `p`, and the `int` object `p` points to.

```
    int *       int
   +–––+       +–––+
p: |   | –––>  |   | 
   +—––+       +–––+
```

Space for the variable `p` is allocated on entry to `foo` and released when the function exits.

Space for the `int` object that `p` points to (which we refer to with the expression `*p`) is allocated by the call to `malloc`, and is not released until you call `free` (or until the program terminates).

When `foo` exits, the variable `p` ceases to exist.  The memory that `p` pointed to is still allocated, but unfortunately you can no longer access it.

Comment: And you can't free it neither because of lack of pointer, not just not access it.